# Cast to undefined failed for value "[object Object]" at path in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to push a mongoose object into another object, as in
Quiz -> Questions(array of questions), here i am trying to push a question object into the questions array after saving the question object. Below is the function which i have written to accomplish the task

```
function addQuestiontoQuiz(req,res,next){
var q = new question({questionBody:req.body.questionBody,
    options:[req.body.option1,req.body.option2,req.body.option3,req.body.option4],
    answer:req.body.answer
});
q.save(function(err,question){
    if(err){
        res.status(422).send("Problem :"+err.message);
    }else {
        quiz.findOneAndUpdate({quizName:req.params.quizName},{$push:{questions:question}},{upsert:true},function(err){
            if(err){
                res.status(422).send("Problem: "+err.message);
            } else
            {
                res.redirect('/quiz/'+req.params.quizName+'/questions');
            }
        });
    }
});
}
```

But i am getting the following error while doing this :

```
Cast to undefined failed for value "[object Object]" at path "questions"
```

Here is the quiz model

```
var question = App.model('question');
var schema = mongoose.Schema({
quizName:{type:String,unique:true,required:true},
questions:[{type:question}]
 });
```

The question model :

```
var schema = mongoose.Schema({
questionBody :{type:String,required:true},
options:[String],
numOfOptions:{type:Number},
answer:{type:String,required:true}
 });
```

I am stuck at this point, please help.

Comment: Please, add the definition for your `Quiz` model.

Comment: I have appended the model definition to the question sir,

Comment: What about the definition for the `Question` model?

Comment: yup added that as well

Comment: the question object is getting persisted properly, but it is not getting pushed into the quiz object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is a result of the incorrect schema and model definitions.

Schemas should be defined as instances of the [mongoose.Schema](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html) constructor. Models should be defined with the `mongoose.model` method which should supplied the schema as a second argument.

You can refactor the `Question` model definition in this manner:

```
// Note the use of 'new mongoose.Schema'
var questionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  questionBody: {type:String, required:true},
  options: [String],
  numOfOptions: {type:Number},
  answer: {type:String,required:true}
});

// The 'mongoose.model' method should be given the schema definition.
var Question = mongoose.model('Question', questionSchema);

module.exports = Question;
```

The `Quiz` model can be defined as such:

```
var quizSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  quizName: {type:String,unique:true,required:true},
  // A quiz has many questions.
  questions:[{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Question'}]
});

var Quiz = mongoose.model('Quiz', quizSchema);

module.exports = Quiz;
```

There is no need to use the `$push` query operator. Once a `quiz` instance has been obtained from the `findOneAndUpdate` command, the `question` instance can be added directly to the `questions` array of the `quiz` instance:

```
quiz.findOneAndUpdate({quizName:req.params.quizName}, function(err, quiz) {
  if(err) {
    res.status(422).send("Problem: "+err.message);
  } else {
    quiz.questions.push(question);
    res.redirect('/quiz/'+req.params.quizName+'/questions');
  }
});
```

Comment: i am already doing that with the following statements 

var Model = mongoose.model('question',schema);

module.exports = Model;

Comment: When i removed the $push query operator i am getting this error::
return this._schema.caster.cast(value, this._parent, false);
                               ^

TypeError: this._schema.caster.cast is not a function

Comment: That is good but I refactored the model definitions in the answer. I also refactored the call to `findOneAndUpdate`.

Comment: Can you redefine your models as I suggested and refactor the call to `findOneAndUpdate` ? If you encounter any errors afterwards, you can post them here.

Comment: No luck on that either

Comment: return this._schema.caster.cast(value, this._parent, false); ^ TypeError: this._schema.caster.cast is not a function

Comment: I just corrected the error in the solution. You'll need to change this line: `questions:[Question]` to this: `questions:[{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Question}]`

Comment: Ok cool, but this is pushing only the object id into the quiz object, how do i get the entire question object to get into the quiz object

Comment: i changed it to questions:[{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Object, ref: 'Question}], works like a charm thanks a lot